# Login and redirect to user home page

Tags: php, javascript, html

The problem I can't currently solve is when a user logs in. They arrive at the site (index.php) and enter username and password, which gets submitted via a Post form back to index.php - if there are incorrect details then they get an error message. But if successful then I would like them to be taken to their user home page - but I can't do this! I am left presenting them with a link to the home page, which is more than a little clunky.

Seems there must be an obviously solution - never seen a site before that didn't redirect! Not sure is the answer is PHp, HTML, or Javascript.

EDIT:

Sorry if the question wasn't up to scratch - still learning here. Have tried to put the redirect in an if statement but still won't work. I think ideally the redirect would be top of the code, but can't see how to do that and retain the login procedure? Code as follows:

```
if (isset($_POST['user']))
{
$user = sanitizeString($_POST['user']);
$pass = sanitizeString($_POST['pass']);

$salt = "randomsalt";
$md5pass = md5($salt . $pass);

if ($user == "" || $pass == "")
{
    $error = "Not all fields were entered<br />";
}
else
{
    $query = "SELECT username,password FROM users
              WHERE username='$user' AND password='$md5pass'";


    if (mysql_num_rows(queryMysql($query)) == 0)
    {
        $error = "Username/Password invalid<br />";
    }
    else
    {
        $_SESSION['user'] = $user;
        $_SESSION['pass'] = $pass;

        header("Location: http://localhost:8888/profile.php?view=$user");

        exit;

    }
}
```

}

Thanks

Rich

EDIT 2:

Thanks for your help guys - still couldn't resolve then need to have the re-direct at the top of the page, but equally having to have my login script in place. In the end solved it with:

```
echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=profile.php?view=$user\">";
```

In place of the header and exit rows above.

Thanks again

Rich

Comment: "But if successful then I would like them to be taken to their user home page - but I can't do this! I am left presenting them with a link to the home page, which is more than a little clunky" - Not sure how we are meant to help, there really isn't enough information here to help.

Answer (score 4):

You are probably redirecting wrong.  First, put this at the very top of `index.php`:

```
<?php
/* Redirect browser */
header("Location: http://newPath/newPage.php/");

/* Make sure that code below does not get executed when we redirect. */
exit;
?>
```

This is a simple redirect with an `exit` statement to stop all processing afterwards, so you can just test to see if the redirect is working.  If it works, then add a condition to the redirect, so something like

```
<?php
if (/*login credentials are valid*/){
    /* Redirect browser */
    header("Location: http://newPath/newPage.php/");

    /* Make sure that code below does not get executed when we redirect. */
    exit;
}
?>
```

but, of course replace `/*login credentials are valid*/` with a call to a function or whatever that actually checks the credentials and returns a boolean value.

Comment: Rich wants that if username and password is correct then only redirect to home page otherwise show error msg. Where did you print error msg ?

Comment: @Angel His issue is the redirect.  His page is not redirecting for some reason.  So, that is the problem I addressed in my answer.

Comment: read this : "if there are incorrect details then they get an error message. But if successful then I would like them to be taken to their user home page"

Answer (score -1):

this solution is for php, hope this will help you.

```
$user_name = $_POST['username']; // posting value through form
$pass_word = $_POST['password']; // posting value through form

$sql = mysql_query("select 1 from admin_users where username='".$user_name."' and password='".$pass_word."'"); // checking username and password in database

if ($sql)    

{echo "Invalid User Name/Password";}

else

{header("Location: homepage.php"); exit;}
```

Comment: Exactly how is this a solution? Where are `login` and `password` defined? in what context do they line up with what the OP asked?

Comment: you better read Question first, as Rich said "if there are incorrect details then they get an error message. But if successful then I would like them to be taken to their user home page" he only care's about how to redirect user to homepage. and for you i am gonna edit my post.

Comment: That's my point, though, right? You've given a small snippet of code without any explanation as to what's happening.

Comment: thank for pointing out though, but you have to limited according to question, according to Question Rich knows all other thing, except how to redirect on homepage so i little bit specific. Thanks for your comments!

Comment: Welcome to [SQL injection attacks](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/37214-sql-injection-what-it-is-and-how-to-prevent-it/)

Answer (score -2):

take username and password in a variable.

```
$username = $_POST['username'];
$pwd = $_POST['password'];
```

Compare this with your table like below:

```
$sql = mysql_query("select * from tbl_users where username='".$username."' and password='".$pwd."'");
if(mysql_num_rows($sql)>0){
header("Location:homepage.php");
}else{
echo "Invalid username or password ";
}
```

This will work.

Comment: Yes, assigning post data to local variables sanitizes the input so well.

Comment: Can anyone know me whats wrong in this answer? why -ve marking?

Comment: Let's say I submit the string "'; DROP TABLE tbl_users;" as my username. What exactly are you sending to MySQL if I do that? This is called SQL Injection Attack, which is something you should google if you value your databases.

Comment: But if you drop table then how will you authenticate users' login. I have just given an example of table name called "tbl_users". Otherwise query is ok. If you don't think so then post your answer.